# How to load CSV data in snappydata table with rowstore mode using JDBC connection

Tags: scala, jdbc, gemfire, snappydata

Hi i am starting to learning the snappydata rowstore [link](http://rowstore.docs.snappydata.io/docs/disk_storage/persist-hdfs-topics.html) there i tried all the example its working , but i need to store the csv , json data in  snappydata table, in the example they are using manually connecting the snappy-shell and creating the tables and inserting the records,and another option for JDBC client [link](https://github.com/SnappyDataInc/snappydata/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples/snappydata/JDBCExample.scala) , i am tried this way but i dont know how to load csv and store in snappy table,then i tried another method  direct query based access in snappydata store also [link](https://discuss.pivotal.io/hc/en-us/articles/201569486-Using-SQuirreL-SQL-with-GemFire-XD) ,if anyone knows how to store csv data in snappytable using jdbc please share me, Thank you..

Answer (score 0):

You should go through the SnappyData docs - http://snappydatainc.github.io/snappydata/. The "How-to" section has loading from CSV examples ... http://snappydatainc.github.io/snappydata/howto/#how-to-load-data-in-snappydata-tables

```
val someCSV_DF = snSession.read.csv("Myfile.csv")
someCSV_DF.write.insertInto("MyTable")
```

Comment: As per the snappy data documentation , its working properly but its taking only the spark memory, not in snappy table,even i execute the example its executing but its not creating any table in the snappy row-store table,except the JDBC client connection.while using jdbc client the table will creating, but i tried csv reader in the jdbc connection but its taking the local file path,but i need to connect cloud storage, so its showing the File not found Exception.could you tell me how to use cloud csv file in jdbc connection Thank you..

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to use SQL (not Spark scala) to load CSV file data from cloud storage like S3? Normally, something like this would work         'create external table t1 using CSV options (path 's3:.....') '

Comment: Thank you @jagsr, could you tell me how to use csv Option for snappy rowstore mode, while using snappy rowstore there don't have a any option for loading csv in the snappy table.I tried  but its showing the error on " Was expecting one of: <EOF> "buckets" "eviction" "expire" "initsize" "local" "maxpartsize" "partition" "persistent"" but there is no Option for the path,Could you tell me how to how to use path in snappydata rowstore..Thank you.

Comment: You first create an external table ( see example in <product>/quickstart/scripts ) and then load into Row table from this external table. .e.g. `CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE T1
  USING CSV OPTIONS(path '..<directory>', header 'true')  .... CREATE TABLE YOUR_ROW_TABLE USING ROW options() AS (SELECT * FROM T1)`

Comment: But i need to store that using Colum table using in HDFS "CREATE HDFSSTORE streamingstore NameNode 'hdfs://localhost:9000' HomeDir 'streamtables' BatchSize 10 BatchTimeInterval 2000 milliseconds QueuePersistent true MaxWriteOnlyFileSize 200 WriteOnlyFileRolloverInterval 1 minutes;" there have opitons only on the row side only, how to use that in column table , there have a any options are available if its please share me thank you..

Comment: sorry. The HDFS Store feature is only supported on Row tables. If you simply want to store any table to HDFS (write_only), it is super simple to do with Spark APIs. `snappySession.table("yourColumnTable").write.parquet("hdfs://<path>")`